# Unable to join two lists in the correct position

Tags: python, list, join

So I have this function that i would like to open a csv file containing data about a sports team. From there i would like it to calculate the teams total points as i am only given the teamname , games played , wins, draws losses. I have calculated the scores but now am unable to add them back to the list in the correct position.

Is there anyway I can get it to output something like this for every team in the list:

```
'ManchesterUnited,20,15,5,5,50'
```

I have tried:

```
Zip(info,score)

[info + score for info, score in zip(info, score)]
```

but it will not work as the score list is a list of integers not strings.

and is there a way i can store this list in a variable for use in a later function ?

edit :
Here is an image of the csv file: 
[csvFile](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uUHFu.png)

I also uploaded the file to tiny upload if that helps:
[link](http://s000.tinyupload.com/?file_id=19511738461449542437)

Comment: what is the value of `info` ? is it the team name ?

Comment: sorry should have been more specific , info is all of the team information. so there name , games played , wins , draws and losses.

Comment: You know, Python has a csv module so you don't have to reinvent the wheel each time.

Comment: Post your csv file sample

Comment: @polku I didn't actually know this but my lecturer requested avoiding using libraries and modules

Comment: @L_S would you like a link to the file or just for me to post the information stored in it ?

Comment: Post a sample of 3 lines with headers

Comment: @L_S added a link to the file and to the image of the file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a demo, it might help:

```
    >>> x = ['ManchesterUnited', "India"]
    >>> y = [[20,15,5,5,50], [4,5,6,7,8]]
    >>> [", ".join(s) for s in list(zip(x, [", ".join(map(str,t)) for t in y]))]
    ['ManchesterUnited, 20, 15, 5, 5, 50', 'India, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8']
```

@Nvision
For your case, after taking a look at the `csv` file and then getting `score` and `info`, the following approach will work:

```
>>> score = [56, 50, 27, 49, 56, 33, 33, 25, 47, 55, 31, 36, 40, 27, 31, 66, 24, 30, 19, 22]

>>> info = ['Manchester City,27,17,5,5', 'Arsenal,26,15,5,6', 'Leicester City,27,7,6,14', 'Manchester United,26,13,10,3', 'Tottenham Hotspur,27,16,8,3', 'West Ham United,28,9,6,13', 'Southampton,26,9,6,11', 'Crystal Palace,27,7,4,16', 'Everton,28,13,8,7', 'Liverpool,28,16,7,5', 'Watford,27,8,7,12', 'Stoke City,28,9,9,10', 'West Bromwich Albion,28,11,7,10', 'Swansea City,28,8,3,17', 'Burnley,28,9,4,15', 'Chelsea,27,21,3,3', 'Hull City,28,6,6,16', 'Bournemouth,28,8,6,14', 'Sunderland,27,5,4,18', 'Middlesborough,27,4,10,13']

>>> result = [i + ',' + str(j) for i, j in zip(info, score)]
>>> result
['Manchester City,27,17,5,5,56', 'Arsenal,26,15,5,6,50', 'Leicester City,27,7,6,14,27', 'Manchester United,26,13,10,3,49', 'Tottenham Hotspur,27,16,8,3,56', 'West Ham United,28,9,6,13,33', 'Southampton,26,9,6,11,33', 'Crystal Palace,27,7,4,16,25', 'Everton,28,13,8,7,47', 'Liverpool,28,16,7,5,55', 'Watford,27,8,7,12,31', 'Stoke City,28,9,9,10,36', 'West Bromwich Albion,28,11,7,10,40', 'Swansea City,28,8,3,17,27', 'Burnley,28,9,4,15,31', 'Chelsea,27,21,3,3,66', 'Hull City,28,6,6,16,24', 'Bournemouth,28,8,6,14,30', 'Sunderland,27,5,4,18,19', 'Middlesborough,27,4,10,13,22']
```

Comment: I am getting :TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable  , what am I doing wrong ?

Comment: @Nvision Please provide demo value of `info` and `score` in order to help you better

Comment: added a link to the file and an image of the file, maybe that can help

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the problem can be simplified by processing the data file once, going line-by-line, calculating your new result, and adding that to a new list.

For example:

```
with open("league.csv","r") as league:
    info = league.readlines()
newInfo = []
for lineIndex in info[2:]:
    data = lineIndex.strip('\n').split(',')
    score = str(int(data[2])*3+int(data[3]))
    data.append(score)
    newInfo.append(','.join(data))

for index in newInfo:
    print(index)
```

Comment: I got the error: ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'Premier League' any ideas ?

Answer (score 0):

You can do

```
import csv
with open('premierleague.csv') as f:
    f.next()
    reader = csv.DictReader(f)
    for i in reader:
        data = ",".join([i['Team'], i['Matches Won'], i['Matches Drawn'], i['Matches Lost'], str(int(i['Matches Won'])*3)])
        print data
```